# Network automation module error on GNS3

Tags: docker, networking, automation

On Ubuntu 16.04, fully up to date.

Running GNS3 with the Network Automation module installed. However, when trying to use the module I get the following error:

> *Error while setting up node: Docker has returned an error: [Errno 13] Cannot connect to host docker:80 ssl:False [Permission denied]*

I have followed [THIS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-16-04) in order to install docker correctly.

Not really sure what else I can try but I'm open to suggestions!

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, after installing docker from the link i posted you just need to log off and on to update the groups!